When can $X_n=O_p(a_n)$ imply $\mathbb E[X_n] = O(a_n)$?
Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset \mathbb R^d$ be a sequence of uniformly bounded random variables which converges almost surely to $0$, and is stochastically dominated by a sequence of positive numbers $(a_n)\to 0$, that is,
$$\|X_n\|\le B\ \ \forall n,\ \text{ and }\ \forall\varepsilon>0, \exists M,N>0 : \mathbb P\left(\left|{\frac{\|X_n\|}{a_n}}\right|>M\right)<\varepsilon ,\;\forall \;n>N. \tag1$$
(Here $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the usual Euclidean norm, but clearly this doesn't matter.)
First, almost sure convergence of $(X_n)$ implies convergence in probability, and since the sequence is uniformly bounded, it is uniformly integrable and therefore converges in $L^1$ to $0$, that is $\mathbb E[\|X_n\|]\to 0 $ as $n\to\infty$.
My question is : what are some sufficient, non-trivial conditions I can impose on $(X_n)$ so that $\mathbb E[\|X_n\|]$ is dominated by (a function of) $a_n$ ? That is, under what conditions can we have the following
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\mathbb E[\|X_n\|]}{a_n} <\infty \tag2 $$
(or in the same spirit, one might replace $(a_n)$ in $(2)$ above by $a_n'\equiv f(a_n)$ for some non-decreasing function $f$) ?
The discussion in a closely related post suggests to assume that $\frac{\left\|X_n\right\|}{a_n} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{\left\|X_n\right\| > c a_n\right\}}$ is uniformly dominated by an integrable r.v. $X$ and apply reverse Fatou's lemma, but this is quite hard to verify (and doesn't seem to hold for my problem), so I'm hoping that someone might come up with another idea. I believe that the uniform boundedness and almost sure convergence assumptions on $X_n$ should help, but so far I do not see how to exploit them...
Thanks in advance for any help !
